# CSV vs XML parsing speed Python

Tags: python, xml, django, csv

For a project I'm working on I need to digest large data feeds which are available in either CSV or XML formats and import the data into Django models. Which format should I choose for performance?

Comment: Why don't you measure it? This depends entirely on the data contained and how much processing either format would require before it is usable to you.

Comment: In theory, CSV is faster. But you need test it yourself to know how much.

Comment: @martijn-pieters I was just wondering if there was a clear winner. If it's close then I will of course test it.

Comment: If you have very large data-sets I would think that CSV has to be much more efficient because you can load the data in chunks and process it line at a time whereas that is not necessarily true for XML. Both CSV and XML and pretty easy and are both pretty fast due to all the C libraries so I would choose whatever is easier for you to use.